# If two polynomials satisfy $|P|^{2}=|Q|^{2}$, then they must have the same number of zeros, including the multiplicities.

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, roots, solution-verification

I am trying to prove the claim that:

> If two polynomials satisfy $|P|^{2}=|Q|^{2}$, then they must have the same number of zeros, including the multiplicities.

It is immediate that they must have the same number of zeros, since if $P(\alpha)=0$ but $Q(\alpha)\neq 0$ for some $\alpha$, then $|P(\alpha)|^{2}=0\neq|Q(\alpha)|^{2}$, a contradiction.

The multiplicities are tricker, I had a proof but I don't know if it is correct:

If $P(z)=(z-\alpha)^{n}h_{1}(z)$ and $Q(z)=(z-\alpha)^{m}h_{2}(z)$ with $h_{1}(\alpha), h_{2}(\alpha)\neq 0$ holomorphic. WLOG assume $n=m+1$.

Then, $|P|^{2}=|Q|^{2}$ implies that $$|x-\alpha|^{2m+2}|h_{1}(x)|^{2}=|x-\alpha|^{2m}|h_{2}(x)|^{2},$$ so that $$|x-\alpha|^{2m}\Big(|x-\alpha|^{2}|h_{1}(x)|^{2}-|h_{2}(x)|^{2}\Big)=0.$$

This implies that, for $x\neq\alpha$, $$|h_{2}(x)|^{2}=|x-\alpha|^{2}|h_{1}(x)|^{2},$$ so that $$|q(x)|^{2}=|x-\alpha|^{2m+2}|h_{1}(x)|^{2},$$ so $$q(x)=\pm C(x-\alpha)^{m+1}h_{1}(x),$$ where $C$ is a constant of modulus $1$.

So the multiplicities are the same.

Is my proof correct? It seems really wired, but I don't know where I got wrong.

Thank you!

**Edit 1:**

I am editing this post to give a proof following the idea of "user8675309". In fact, in the problem I faced, $|P|^{2}=|Q|^{2}$ only on $\mathbb{S}^{1}$, but all the roots of $P$ and $Q$ lie on $\mathbb{S}^{1}$. This makes the thing a little bit more complicated. Below is the proof with this restricted condition:

$|P|^{2}=|Q|^{2}$ on $\mathbb{S}^{1}$ implies that there is some polynomial with real coefficients, say $G(z)$, is given by $P(z)$ times its conjugate or $Q(z)$ times its conjugate, for $z\in\mathbb{S}^{1}$. Since $G$ is the same polynomial, $P$ and $Q$ must have same zeros counting multiplicities on $\mathbb{S}^{1}$. But all of their zeros lie on $\mathbb{S}^{1}$, so we are done.

**I will leave this post open for a few days, in case of further discussion or anyone post a solution so that I can accept it. Then I will answer my own post.**

Comment: If I’m reading this correctly isn’t it just saying some polynomial with real coefficients G(x) is given by p(x) times it’s conjugate, or q(x) times it’s conjugate.  G is the same polynomial for both so has the same roots... working backward implies it for q and p

Comment: @user8675309 OMG you are definitely correct.

Comment: @user8675309 would you mind posting an answer? I believe using your comment will be perfect :)

Comment: Suppose the multiplicities are different and divide by $|x-\alpha|^{2\cdot\text{highest multiplicity}}$ and see what happens as $x\to \alpha$. One side goes to $\infty$ while the other is finite.

Comment: @GabrielRomon oh okay. This is also a good point!

Comment: I would add that the result is true in general for analytic functions on any open set in the plane though here the zeroes may form an infinite discrete set assuming the functions not identically zero - (proof-let $w$ a zero of say $f$ of multiplicity $m \ge 1$ and let $n$ its multiplicity as a zero of $g$, then if $n \ne m$, wlog $n>m$, and dividing by $(z-w)^m$, both $f_1=\frac{f}{(z-w)^m},g_1=\frac{g}{(z-w)^m}$ remain analytic and satisfy the same absolute value relation. $|f_1|^2=|g_1|^2$, on the domain we started with, but now $f_1(w) \ne 0, g_1(w)=0$ and that is a contradiction

Comment: @Conrad wow. Thank you for your brilliant answer!!

Comment: happy to be of help

Comment: $|P|^{2}=|Q|^{2}$ is equivalent to $|P|=|Q|$. So why do you require $|P|^{2}=|Q|^{2}$?

Comment: @PaulFrost oh because I was working on the Riesz-Fejer Lemma, and discussing the uniqueness problem of the polynomial in that lemma, and in that lemma we would have something like $|P|^{2}$. But you are right, I should ask directly about $|P|=|Q|$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the discussion is finished, I am answering my own post to close it.

In fact, in the problem I faced, $|P|^{2}=|Q|^{2}$ only on $\mathbb{S}^{1}$, but all the roots of $P$ and $Q$ lie on $\mathbb{S}^{1}$. This makes the thing a little bit more complicated. Below is the proof with this restricted condition:

$|P|^{2}=|Q|^{2}$ on $\mathbb{S}^{1}$ implies that there is some polynomial with real coefficients, say $G(z)$, is given by $P(z)$ times its conjugate or $Q(z)$ times its conjugate, for $z\in\mathbb{S}^{1}$. Since $G$ is the same polynomial, $P$ and $Q$ must have same zeros counting multiplicities on $\mathbb{S}^{1}$. But all of their zeros lie on $\mathbb{S}^{1}$, so we are done.

I do appreciate user8675309, Gabriel and Conrad for their solution of general cases.